# Cordova corrupt ios platform

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add some ionic native elements e.g. 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera' but i get a err due to the ios platform not being there.

running cordova platform version ios I get:

```
Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
  ios
Available platforms:
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~5.0.0
  ios ~4.5.1
  osx ~4.0.1
  ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
```

So I have ios installed however do deal with this problem i've run `cordova platform rm ios`
then `cordova platform add ios` but I get this error:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@0.0.1
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@0.0.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cordova-ios@0.0.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_logs/2017-12-19T10_09_11_709Z-debug.log
```

I assume this has something to do with the ios platform not having a version associated with it but I can't figure it out.

```
ionic -v
3.19.0
```

PART 2 UPDATE

```
the first step results in:   
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/node_mod
ules/.bin/nopt
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/node_mod
ules/.bin/shjs
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/nod
e_modules/.bin
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/nod
e_modules/bplist-parser
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/nod
e_modules/nopt
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/nod
e_modules/shelljs
rm: could not remove directory (code EACCES): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/nod
e_modules/simctl
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim/
node_modules
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/ios-sim
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios/cordova
rm: could not remove directory (code ENOTEMPTY): /Users/adamgoldberg/Documents/programming/thrive/platforms/ios
```

and then the second line `ionic cordova platform add ios@latest` results in

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@latest

Error: Platform ios already added.

[ERROR] Exception:
```

PART 3 (running npm update -g)

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev' }žnpm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_logs/2017-12-19T21_54_39_809Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try `npm update -g`

Comment: Hey that didn't work, it is also corrupt with errors. Do you know what they are? I've edited the original question to include the errors I've received from running `npm update -g` please refer to PART 3

Comment: Try with with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove ios platform

cordova platform rm ios

2. Add platform via

   ionic cordova platform add ios@latest
3. Add cordova-plugin-camera plugin

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --force

**Update 2:**

Try with "sudo cordova platform rm ios" ,

Then remove "ios" platform from "config.xml" file if exits,

Then remove "ios" folder from physical path as well if exits,

After above three steps

ionic cordova platform add ios@latest

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --force

If you will get same error(EACCES) again then try all command with "sudo"

Comment: That didn't work, I had errors both when rm the ios platform and adding it back using your method. I think something is corrupt. I've edited the original response to include the error messages received from your advice. Please refer to PART 2